# list stays empty even after inserting an element C++

Tags: c++, b-tree

I am trying to insert pointers into a list but every time I try to print the list, or check whats in the list it says its empty. This means that my insertion is incorrect, but I don't understand why, my following classes are:

```
namespace {

  template <typename T>
  pair < node<T>*, bool> addElement (const T& elem, btree<T>* bt) {

     class list < node<T>* >::iterator itr = bt->level().begin();

     if (bt->level().empty()) {
      node <T>*n = new node<T>(elem, bt->max());
      cout << n->getItem() << endl;
      bt->addElem(itr, n);
      return make_pair(n, true);
     }

     for (; itr != bt->level().end(); ++itr) {
        if (elem < (*itr)->getItem()) {
          node <T>* n = new node<T> (elem, bt->max());
          (*itr)->previous()->addNext(n);
          n->addPrev((*itr)->previous());
          n->addNext(*itr);
          (*itr)->addPrev(n);
          bt->addElem(itr, n);
          return make_pair(n, true);
            } else if (elem == (*itr)->getItem()) return make_pair(*itr, false); 
          }

     // other stuff + return statement

}
```

addElem does the following:

```
void addElem (std::_List_iterator<node<T>*>& itr, node <T>* n) { 
  neighbours.insert(itr, n); 
  if (neighbours.empty()) cout << "wa?";
}
```

where `btree` class consists of:

```
size_t maxNodeElems;
list < node<T>*> neighbours;
```

the other things like `addPrev()` and `previous()` are just getters and setters. Anyways, I ran a test file on it that pretty much constructs a `btree`, and calls an `insert` function which directly calls this `addElement` function. But whenever I try to print the list inside the btree, it says its empty and seg faults. I don't understand why it's not storing.

Any help would be appreciated!

NOTE: the "Wa?" keeps printing

Comment: It could be your display code is incorrect. Show the code that prints the tree also.

Comment: @graham.reeds I wrote an `if` statement inside addElem, after the `insert` statement saying `if neighbours is empty print something` which always printed something.

Comment: Learn to use the debugger - that will tell you a lot more about why it's not working. Out of interest, what IDE are you using?

Comment: `itr` is an iterator over `bt->level()`, and you use it to insert an element into `neighbors`. SO, does `bt->level()` return `neighbors`?

Comment: @BjörnPollex yeah, `bt->level()` returns `neighbours` it was too much code, to copy/paste the whole thing into OP

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to keep a sorted list, that's why you have:

```
// find the place to insert elem
for (; itr != bt->level().end(); ++itr) {
    if (elem < (*itr)->getItem()) {
        // insert...
    }
}
```

But if the list is empty (initial state), itr will be probably equal bt->level().end() in the first place, so you will never insert anything...

You also should consider the case when you are trying to insert element for which (elem < (*itr)->getItem()) is always false (the new greatest element in the list). You need to handle that case as well.

Comment: I've handed the greatest element stuff in the parts below which I didn't add to the OP. The first `if` statement handles a list when it is empty, but it doesn't work even if I add an element in intitially